# Why is the GDI DrawString call behaving differently in PrintDocument vs. rendering to an image?

Tags: .net, gdi, printdocument

I am working on a printing application in C# using the PrintDocument class.  I have gotten the physical printing part working the way I want, but one of the requirements is that I save an image file as well.

I have created an image and use the same GDI calls that rendered the printed page.  It looks pretty close except for the text.  The printed page is fine, but the saved image is causing the 8pt Courier font to show up as what appears to be a 0.1pt font.

I have tried adding the following, with no luck:

```
 g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
 g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
```

Any ideas as to why the difference in text rendering?

Answer (score 1):

Not enough code to look at, the posted snippets are not relevant to font scaling.

The big difference between a printed page and an image is the drastic difference in resolution.  600 dpi vs 96 dpi, typically.  Default scaling for the printer is 1 pixel = 0.01 inch, making text and images almost the same size when rendered to the screen vs paper.  Changing that scaling causes the kind of trouble you're having.

Look for any assignments to Graphics.PageUnit in your code, for example.

Comment: I am setting the page unit to pixel.  In trying to simplify the code to post, I am not seeing the behavior anymore.  At this point it boils down to trial and error to figure out where the offending line of code is.